# Should questions about the Semantic Web be considered on-topic?

Tags: discussion

SemWeb is a broad topic, obviously, but there are definitely elements of AI involved.  Generally speaking, should we welcome SemWeb questions?

Answer (score 1):

For those unfamiliar, the [Semantic Web](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_Web) is basically an extension to HTML that calls out the content of certain elements as certain kinds of information. For example, the sentence "John Smith was born in Chicago" would have the name and birthplace marked up appropriately, with a reference to a schema on the enclosing element.

It doesn't seem like the Semantic Web is itself an AI thing, but if questions about artificial intelligence happen to touch on it, I see no reason to reject them.